# Function within For Loop wont give me any output

Tags: scripting

[image: I have also tried the "Do" function, that too does not work]

```
ztar[n_] := Module[{xlist, ylist, points, plots},
  plots = {};
  xlist = {1};
  ylist = {0};
  For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++,
   AppendTo[xlist, Cos[i*(n - 1)/n*Pi]];
   AppendTo[ylist, Sin[i*(n - 1)/n*Pi]];
   points = Transpose[{xlist, ylist}];
   AppendTo[plots, Graphics[Line[points], Axes -> True]]
   ];
  Show[plots, PlotRange -> Full]
  ]
```

I can't figure out how to make a function be called within a For Loop while also giving an output. The output works fine, just not in a For Loop. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `For` loops never return anything. Use `Table` instead: `Table[ztar[i], {i, 1, 9, 2}]`. See [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/27951).

Comment: You can change your For [ ] loop by writing                                                       For[i = 1, i <= 9, i += 2; Print[ztar[i]]]. You must use Print[ ] to have the For[ ] loop show the plots.

Comment: Required reading: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)

Comment: Basic principle: An `"Output"` cell shows the value of an executed statement unless the value is `Null`.  An `"Input "`cell may contain more than one statement and produce more than one `"Output"` cell.  `Print` writes a `"Print"` cell into the evaluation notebook, `CellPrint` can write any type of cell into a notebook, etc. Personally, I avoid `Print[]`, esp. in loops, except for debugging (but still not in loops).  Outside loops, it's mainly a style preference. If just learning *Mma*, style preferences should not be a priority, but avoiding an infinite loop of `Print[]` statements should be.

Comment: A long time ago (pre V5?) `Show` used to do what its name implies: show graphics. Now it is mainly used to combine multiple graphics.  You can semi-emulate the old functionality with `Show[plots, PlotRange -> Full, DisplayFunction -> Print]` or `DisplayFunction -> (CellPrint[ExpressionCell[#, "Output"]] &)`

Answer (score 5):

Try (see @MarcoB's comment)

```
ztar[n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{xy, plots},
xy = Table[{Cos[k (n - 1)/n Pi], Sin[k (n - 1)/n Pi]}, {k, 0, n}];
Graphics[Line[xy]]]

ztar[5]
```

[image]

Comment: The definition should be `ztar[n_Integer?Positive] := ...`

Comment: Thanks for your hint

Answer (score 4):

The issue around `For` not producing an output has been pretty well covered, and I suggest the OP follow the links in the comments. My contribution is to fix what I presume is a defect for cases when `ztar` is passed an even number. Maybe it will also provide some hints for finding alternates to the imperative style.

```
myStarPoints[ptCount_Integer?(GreaterEqualThan[3])] :=
  With[
    {jump = Max[Select[Range@Floor[ptCount/2], CoprimeQ[#, ptCount] &]]},
    With[
      {seq = Mod[jump Range[1 + ptCount], ptCount, 1]},
      CirclePoints[ptCount][[seq]]]]
```

**Comparison**

```
Multicolumn[ztar /@ Range[3, 10], {2, Automatic}]
```

[image]

In the above results, note the dangling ends when the argument is even.

```
Multicolumn[Graphics@*Line /@ myStarPoints /@ Range[3, 10], {2, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I appreciate it.

Why does just adding 2 not work? (look below for my example)

For[i = 3, i <= 9, i += 2; Print[star[i]]]

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the question. If you're asking why the `i+=2` bit doesn't work, then don't worry--that works fine. You're skipping the even values so you never try to generate a star with even points. My point is that your code doesn't produce stars for even inputs that I consider valid (but maybe you do). There is nothing in your code that makes it obvious that it's not intended to work for even inputs. At the same time, it's certainly possible to produce stars with even numbers of points. So, I'm just filling that gap.

Comment: I'm also introducing you to `CirclePoints`, which seems relevant to your code. And I'm showing how you can take values from a list in a particular order/permutation, which allows you to avoid looping constructs in this case. Finally, I'm showing a separation between presentation and "domain", which is an important concept.

Comment: Hi again, and thank you. I think I found the culprit for my error. 

When creating the "star" function, I used a for loop with "i", so when I later try out "For[i = 3, i <= 9, i += 2; Print[star[i]]]", I get wrong output ", but get what I am after by replacing "i" with "k", like this: For[k = 3, k <= 9, k += 2; Print[star[k]]]

Does that make sense?

Again, thank you.

Comment: Actually, no it doesn't. I think we're talking about two completely different things. Maybe I missed a comment thread or something. But I don't think it really matters as long as you're getting your question answered.